# Id is set to NULL when trying to save DomainObject in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have two domain object with the same structure as the class Foo below

```
class Foo {

    static mapping = {
        id column: "old_id_column"
        prop1 column: "old_prop_1"
        ... some more properties ...
    }
}

class Bar {
    ... looks the same as Foo ...
}
```

and in the controllers of the classes I try to accomplish the same thing, creating a new object and saving it to the DB.

When I do this

```
class FooController {

    def methodName() {
        final Foo foo = new Foo()
        foo.prop1 = "val1"
        foo.prop2 = val2
        etc.

        foo.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

Everything works but when I try to do the same in the BarController i get the following exception

**Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'old_id_column', table 'System.db.Bar'; column does not allow nulls.**

I'm trying to model a legacy database so obviously I'm missing something in the configuration of the underlying DB but I can't find anything. Any ideas about things that could raise this exception?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a generator

i.e.

```
id generator:'assigned', column: 'old_id_column', type: 'string'
```

See the documentation @ http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html

Comment: I thought there was some sort of default generator always specified? I just realized that I missed something potentially important yesterday. In the Foo class the id column has type Integer (sqlType _int_) but in the Bar class the id column has type Short (sqlType _smallint_). But reading the hibernate docs (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) this shouldn't be an issue since "_The returned identifier is of type long, short or int_". And it doesn't do any good to specify a generator, I still end up with the same error

Comment: Most probably, because you specify the wrong generator, in the documentation is can be «increment, identity, sequence, hilo, seqhilo, uuid, guid, native, assigned, select, foreign or sequence-identity.» In your case, it shoud be increment.

Comment: Nope i tried different combinations of _generator_, _type_ and _sqltype_ but nothing works and besides isn't the generator always _auto-increment_ as default? So I shouldnt really need to specify a generator.

Comment: Maybe you can add in contraints, id(nullable: true), put the generator to assigned and like that, let the legacy db manage the id generation?

Comment: Uhm doesn't setting the generator to assigned mean that i want to specify the Id myself before sending the object to hibernate? I finaly solved it by changing the Identity Specification of the database. For some reason the only thing that works is to have the DB auto increment and use the defaul generator. Can't get hilo or anything to work...